# Infinite reload on Ajax Stop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a long javascript file which I included a auto reload page every ajax success, however I got infinite ajax reload on this

```
<script>
      var latest;
      var par;
      var widgets;
      var test;
      var $randomId;
      var gridster;
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });
        gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_margins: [10, 10],
            widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
            helper: 'clone',
            resize: {
              enabled: true
            },
            serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
              return {
                id:$($w).attr('id'),
                col: wgd.col,
                row: wgd.row,
                size_x:wgd.size_x,
                size_y:wgd.size_y,
              };
            },
            draggable: {
              stop: function(event, ui) {
                var positions = JSON.stringify(this.serialize());
                var data_id = $(ui.$helper[0]).attr('id'); 
                var size_x = $(ui.$helper[0]).attr('data-sizex');
                var size_y = $(ui.$helper[0]).attr('data-sizey');
                var data_row = $(ui.$helper[0]).attr('data-row');
                var data_col = $(ui.$helper[0]).attr('data-col');
                $.ajax({
                  url: "/partA-save-widgets-positions",
                  type: "POST",
                  data: {
                    'size_y': size_y,
                    'size_x': size_x,
                    'data_row': data_row,
                    'data_col': data_col,
                    'id' : data_id
                  },
                  dataType: "json",
                  error: function(log) {
                    console.log(log);
                  },
                  success: function(log) {
                    //console.log(log);
                  }
                })
              }
            }
        }).data('gridster');
        $.getJSON('/partA-widgets-current-positions', function(data) {
          if (data !=null) {
              var id_name;
            id_name = 'widgets';
            id_name = id_name + data.id;
            $.each(JSON.parse(data.positions), function(i, value) {
              console.log(value);
              $(id_name).attr({
                'data-col': value.col,
                'data-row': value.row,
                'data-sizex': value.size_x,
                'data-sizey': value.size_y
              });
            });
          } else {
            console.log("no data returned");
          }
        })
        function Generator(){};
        Generator.prototype.rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + Date.now();
        Generator.prototype.getId = function() {
          return this.rand++;
        };

        widgetTemplate = function($widgetTitle,$widgetContent){
          idGen = new Generator();
          $randomId = idGen.getId();
          var html = $widgetContent;
          return html;
        },

        addWidget = function($widgetType){
          var mapAPI='<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d253304.652017724!2d125.31098975138514!3d7.25390594287568!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x32f96d9f519e327f%3A0xb53a24589f79c573!2sDavao+City%2C+Davao+del+Sur!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sph!4v1467344380693" width="200" height="150" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

          var costApi = 'https://api.del.icio.us/v1/';
           widgets = {
            'map': widgetTemplate('MAP',mapAPI),
            'cost': widgetTemplate('COST','COST CONTENT'),
            'revenue': widgetTemplate('REVENUE','REVENUE CONTENT'),
            'traffic': widgetTemplate('TRAFFIC','TRAFFIC CONTENT'),
            'admin': widgetTemplate('ADMIN','ADMIN CONTENT'),
            'feedback': widgetTemplate('FEEDBACK','FEEDBACK CONTENT'),
            'default': 'Error/Invalid Input'
          };
        }

        $("ul.dropdown-menu li").click(function() {
          par = $.trim($(this).find("span.widgets").text()); 
          //var data_id = $(".random").closest('div.portlet').attr('data-id');
          var style = $('.ui-resizable').attr('style');   
          idGen = new Generator();
          var $randomId2 = idGen.getId();
          console.log($randomId2);
          switch(par) {
            case "MAP": {
              test = widgets.map;
              break;
            }
            case "COST": {
              test = widgets.cost;
              break;
            }
            case "REVENUE": {
              test = widgets.revenue;
              break;
            }
            case "TRAFFIC": {
              test = widgets.traffic;
              break;
            }
            case "ADMIN": {
              test = widget.admin;
              break;
            }
            case "FEEDBACK": {
              test = widget.feedback;
              break;
            }
            default: {
              console.log(par);
            }
          }
          $.ajax({
            url: '/partA-save',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
            'test': test,
            'widget': par,
            'random_id': $randomId2,
            'style': style
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
          }).success(function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            });
          console.log(par);
          console.log(test);
          console.log($randomId2);
          //return true;
        });
          //delete
        $(".remove").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).closest('div.portlet').attr('data-id');
          $.ajax({
            url: '/partA-delete',
            type: "post",
            data: {
             'id': id
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            //async: false,
            success: function(data) {
              if (data.status == 200) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                  location.reload();
                },5000);
              }
            },
            error: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
        });
        //auto reload page if success
        $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
          window.location.reload();
        });
      });  
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be your infinite loop.

```
$.getJSON:call // async 
$(document).ajaxStop(fn) // bind event
$.getJSON:success // ajaxStop:event
```

You could try putting the $(document).ajaxStop(fn) binding inside of the $.getJSON callback

Comment: This will just stop the callback but not reload the page automatically example if other functions is fired

Comment: Its stops the infinite window reload, when you attach the $(document).ajaxStop(fn) within the success message, then it should fire on the next ajax call.